# Creating a query to subtract different values from a single column into a new column

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Poorly worded title, but I can't think of a succinct way to describe my problem.

I have a table with the following columns:

```
year | month | basin_id | value
```

I need to take the values for all basin_ids of one year/month and subtract from that the corresponding values for all basin_ids of another year/month, and store the resulting values in such a way that they are still associated with their respective basin_ids.

This seems like it should be a rather simple query/subquery, and I can calculate the difference in values just fine with:

```
SELECT (val1.value-val2.value)
FROM value_table_1 as val1, 
     value_table_2 as val2 
WHERE val1.basin_id=val2.basin_id
```

where value_table_1 and value_table_2 are temporary tables I've made by segregating all values associated with year1/month1 and year2/month2 for the sake of simplifying my query.

My problem from here is I get a column with all of the new values, but not with their associated basins. How can I achieve this? I am writing this within a plpgsql stored procedure, if that helps.

Say my table is as follows:

```
year | month | basin_id | value
-----+-------+----------+-------
2017 |   04  |   123    |  10
2017 |   04  |   456    |  6
2017 |   05  |   123    |  12
2017 |   05  |   456    |  4
```

and I'm given the inputs:

```
year1 := 2017
month1 := 04
year2 := 2017
month2 := 05
```

I want to get the following table as a result:

```
 basin_id | value
----------+------
   123    |  -2
   456    |  2
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this..

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES
    ( 2010, 02, 5, 8 ),
    ( 2013, 05, 5, 3 )
  ) AS t( year, month, basinid, value );

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bar
AS
  SELECT basinid,
    f1.year AS f1y, f1.month AS f1m,
    f2.year AS f2y, f2.month AS f2m,
    f1.value-f2.value AS value
  FROM foo AS f1
  INNER JOIN foo as f2
    USING (basinid);

 basinid | f1y  | f1m | f2y  | f2m |     value
---------+------+-----+------+-----+----------
       5 | 2010 |   2 | 2010 |   2 |        0
       5 | 2010 |   2 | 2013 |   5 |        5
       5 | 2013 |   5 | 2010 |   2 |       -5
       5 | 2013 |   5 | 2013 |   5 |        0
(4 rows)

SELECT *
FROM bar
WHERE f1y = 2013
  AND f1m = 5
  AND f2y = 2010
  AND f2m = 2;
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Thank you very much, I'll accept the answer when it allows me.

Comment: Sorry just one last question - how can I give the final column of values a name so that I can query it? EDIT: nevermind, just added "as value" to the end of the "f1.value-f2.value" statement